# Shell Script and SQL results

Tags: shell, postgresql

I currently want to extract a value from a SQL command responde

somehting like this:

```
psql db -c "SELECT COUNT(test) FROM tbTest;"
```

the result is:

```
 count
------
 33176
(1 row)
```

I want to extract the 33176 value... is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is always return in that format (expected result on line 3), you can use this:

```
psql db -c "SELECT COUNT(test) FROM tbTest;" | tail -n 2 | head -n 1
```

The explanation:

> `tail -n 2` will get the last 2 line and then processed by `head -n 1` which mean, get first 1 line.

Comment: A.H. provides a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 28):

Why mucking with the unwanted stuff? Simply use some `psql` options...

```
> psql -At -c "SELECT COUNT(test) FROM tbTest;" db
115899
```

Comment: simplify to: psql db -Atc 'SELECT count(test) FROM tbtest'

Comment: +1. This is especially useful if you want to select multiple columns, as it removes whitespace.

Comment: from PostgreSQL 9.6 onwards, you should also add a `-X` to suppress execution of an `psqlrc` file (till 9.5 `-c` did imply that).

Answer (score 4):

By enclosing the complete shell command in backticks, you can retrieve its result into a shell variable:

```
#/bin/sh

THECOUNT=`psql -A -t -c 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbTest;' db`
echo "the count = $THECOUNT"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: actually, this does not work, sorry.  But bellow works.

<strike>If the result is always 4 lines, and without invoking any other commands that create a process:</strike>

```
(read; read; read count; read ) < <(psql db -c "SELECT COUNT(test) FROM tbTest;")
echo "$count"
```

This also work:

**End edit**

```
psql db -c "SELECT COUNT(test) FROM tbTest;" | (read; read; read count; read; echo "$count")
```

Warning: the `count` variable will not be available out of the parentheses because the pipe (`|`) launch a new process.  So this does not work:

```
psql db -c "SELECT COUNT(test) FROM tbTest;" | (read; read; read count; read)
echo "$count"
```

**Edit:**

If you want count in a variable, you can:

```
count=$(psql db -c "SELECT COUNT(test) FROM tbTest;" | (read; read; read count_tmp; read; echo "$count_tmp"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept to launch a process, but not two (head and tail), you could:

```
psql db -c "SELECT COUNT(test) FROM tbTest;" | sed -n -e '3p'
```

This always assume that the output of psql will be 4 lines and you need the 3rd one.